# How to connect to MySQL database using Java on another PC?

Tags: java, mysql

I have made a simple program that uses the connectivity String:

```
Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3305/project", "root", "xxxx");
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
```

Here 'project' is my database name and 'xxxx' is the password.

I have then created an .exe file that works fine on my own computer.

But how can other people on another computer use my program? Do they have to install MySQL? Or Can they access my computer's database on their computer?

Comment: Yeah you can you just need to replace `localhost` with `Your public IP`. And make sure the port is good.

Comment: 'com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure'

Comment: I am getting this exception...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql       Peter John Joesph's Answer try that